# Remove Blank Spaces from parameter SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to do a report on SSRS and the first parameter I have to enter it manually or can Copy paste it from a excel file(one by one). Sometimes there are spaces before the ID. 
The other 2 parameters are dependent on the first parameter.

I am trying to figure our what can be done in order to just take the ID when entered into the parameter box. I have attached a picture for your reference.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to use this parameter in a SQL query?

If so, in your query why not just trim the leading spaces from the value like this:

```
where ID = ltrim(@ID)
```

If I have misunderstood, please add some more information to help clarify exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: I did the same thing first but it did not work. But later on I realized that I did not use the same in all the available datasets. Thank you very much.